# Regular Expression for address validation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is SQL Server 2008 query.

I am searching for records where home address Start with '#' and then followed by digits and then Letters with no spaces.

Here's an example of addresses in the table

```
Create table dbo.temp(Address Varchar(200))

INSERT into dbo.temp VALUES('#1000munoz River St')
INSERT into dbo.temp VALUES('#656ave. Whitehall')
INSERT into dbo.temp VALUES('#12 avenue')
INSERT into dbo.temp VALUES('13 Main St')
```

I want to pick only

```
#1000munoz River St
#656ave. Whitehall
```

i.e. 1st character always '#', followed by 1 or more digits, followed by 1 or more alphabets. I do not want spaces between number and alphabets like record number 3.

I tried

```
Select * 
from dbo.temp 
where charindex('#', Address) = 1 
  and Address like '[#][0-9]^[:b][A-Za-z]%'
```

This is not returning any values and I am not sure why.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks
Rs

Comment: SQL Server does not support regular expressions natively.  The `like` pattern matching is much more limited.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't support regular expressions.  It has a much more limited syntax.  I believe this works for your examples:

```
where address like '#[0-9]%[a-zA-Z] %' and
      address like '#%[0-9][a-zA-Z] %'
```

This doesn't work for all examples, but it might help.

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same problem and fixed it using Master Data Services Functions. We really needed RegExp on SqlServer and finally got a function like this one:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [RegexExtract](@input [nvarchar](4000), @pattern [nvarchar](4000), @group [nvarchar](4000), @mask [tinyint]) RETURNS [nvarchar](4000) WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER, RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT AS EXTERNAL NAME [Microsoft.MasterDataServices.DataQuality].[Microsoft.MasterDataServices.DataQuality.SqlClr].[RegexExtract] GO
```

Follow this link to get more info:https://dyball.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/sql-2008-r2-regular-expressions/