# Modify SQL Server Regex Function to strip out multiple numbers and emails

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-function

I have the following SQL function which strips out numbers in a string, which works fine apart from it is removing ALL numbers. I want to remove telephone numbers - this would usually be 5 or more numbers in a row e.g. 01234 567890.

I would also like the same function to strip out email addresses at the same time.

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[RemoveNumericCharacters](@Temp VarChar(1000))
RETURNS VarChar(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @NumRange as varchar(50) = '%[0-9]%'

    While PatIndex(@NumRange, @Temp) > 0
        Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@NumRange, @Temp), 1, '')

    Return @Temp
End
GO
```

Here are my 2 separate RegEx patterns that I have been playing with:

- Matches numbers: http://rubular.com/r/1waXa33pUN
- Matches email address: http://rubular.com/r/amGVv7hMEc

Any and all advice is appreciated...

Comment: Would you be able to use a [CLR function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189876(v=sql.105).aspx) instead, so that you can use a .NET regex?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I am not quite sure what that entails... I am using .net for the project. Do you have an example?

Comment: There is quite a lot of information if you follow the link in my previous comment. The CLR function is run *within* SQL Server.

Comment: email addresses are tough as far as regex.  I would go with a CLR and use a combination of regex and splitting strings by the space before and after the at (@) then test if it is valid and needs to be removed by using .Net's EmailAddressAttribute... For example your regex doesn't allow for .gov.ca, tlds longer than 5 characters (quick search says 24 is current longest)  Plus technically you can have more characters than alpha numberic hyphen underscore period in the email/name portion of the address........ Seeing your project is using .net what about using application layer to do this work?

Comment: @James Check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37735020/regular-expression-for-address-validation/37737827#37737827